# best way to resolve collisions in hashing strings

Tags: hash

I got asked this question at an interview and said to use a second has function, but the interviewer kept probing me for other answers. Anyone have other solutions?

Comment: Chaining costs one pointer per node and solves all your problems, at the cost of losing locality of reference. (which will be lost by secondary hashing, too)

Comment: Hashing for what purpose? Passwords? MD5 file hash? Dictionaries/hashsets?

Comment: @Darjan for dictionaries

Comment: Fixed dictionaries (no inserts/deletes) ?

Answer (score 2):

> best way to resolve collisions in hashing strings
>   "with continuous inserts"

Assuming the inserts are of strings whose contents can't be predicted, then reasonable options are:

1. Use a displacement list, so you try a number of offsets from the
   hashed-to bucket until you find a free bucket (modding by table
   size).  Displacement lists might look something like { 3, 5, 11,
   19... } etc. - ideally you want to have the difference between
   displacements not be the sum of a sequence of other displacements.
2. rehash using a different algorithm (but then you'd need yet another
   algorithm if you happen to clash twice etc.)
3. root a container in the
   buckets, such that colliding strings can be searched for. Typically
   the number of buckets should be similar to or greater than the
   number of elements, so elements per bucket will be fairly small and
   a brute-force search through an array/vector is a reasonable
   approach, but a linked list is also credible.

Comparing these, displacement lists tend to be fastest (because adding an offset is cheaper than calculating another hash or support separate heap & allocation, and in most cases the first one or two displacements (which can reasonably be by a small number of buckets) is enough to find an empty bucket so the locality of memory use is reasonable) though they're more collision prone than an alternative hashing algorithm (which should approach #elements/#buckets chance of further collisions).  With both displacement lists and rehashing you have to provide enough retries that in practice you won't expect a complete failure, add some last-resort handling for failures, or accept that failures may happen.

Answer (score 0):

Use a linked list as the hash bucket.  So any collisions are handled gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach: You might want to concider using a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) instead of a hash table for dictionaries of strings.

The up side of this approach is you get `O(|S|)` worst case complexity for seeking/inserting each string [where |S| is the length of that string]. Note that hash table allows you only average case of `O(|S|)`, where the worst case is `O(|S|*n)` [where `n` is the size of the dictionary]. A trie also does not require rehashing when load balance is too high.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we are not using [a perfect hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) (which you usually don't have) the hash tells you that:

- if the hashes are different, the objects are distinct
- if the hashes are the same, the objects are *probably* the same (if good hashing function is used), but *may* still be distinct.

So in a hashtable, the collision will be resolved with some additional checking if the objects are actually the same or not (this brings some performance penalty, but according to [Amdahl's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law), you still gained a lot, because collisions rarely happen for good hashing functions). In a dictionary you just need to resolve that rare collision cases and assure you get the right object out.

Using another non-perfect hash function will not resolve anything, it just reduces the chance of (another) collision.

Comment: "if the hashes are the same, the objects are probably the same" - only true if the number of elements is not excessive for the number of hash buckets.

Comment: @TonyDelroy You are right about that, in such case 'probably' and 'may' are not the right words, because the probability varies with distribution. That's why the italics, but I was not specific enough about that.